# SSRS - Using specific Row Number

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I have a SQL query where I am getting the row number for a count of employees per division and per month at the beginning of the month and the end of the month. To do that, I use a payroll end date which is a weekly date. So in essence I have 4 dates where employee counts are shown. Some months have 5 dates which makes the row count for that month 5 instead of 4.

I then need to build an SSRS report to show only the first employee count and the last employee count per division, per month. I have the first number since I am using `=IIF(Fields!RowNumber.Value = 1, Fields!EMPCOUNT.Value, 0)`

The problem I have now is getting the last employee count where I need to conditionally select a count where row number needs to be 5 if exists or 4 if it doesn't exist. I'm not sure how to get the expression to work in SSRS. Sample data is below.

```
PRCo    EMPCOUNT    udDivision    PREndDate         ROWNUM  Type
 1       89          Civil     2018-01-06 00:00:00    1       1
 1       97          Civil     2018-01-13 00:00:00    2       1
 1       97          Civil     2018-01-20 00:00:00    3       1
 1       97          Civil     2018-01-27 00:00:00    4       1
 1       16         Colorado   2018-01-06 00:00:00    1       1
 1       18         Colorado   2018-01-13 00:00:00    2       1
 1       14         Colorado   2018-01-20 00:00:00    3       1
 1       10         Colorado   2018-01-27 00:00:00    4       1
 1       94          Civil     2018-02-03 00:00:00    1       2
 1       91          Civil     2018-02-10 00:00:00    2       2
 1       92          Civil     2018-02-17 00:00:00    3       2
 1       91          Civil     2018-02-24 00:00:00    4       2
 1       16         Colorado   2018-02-03 00:00:00    1       2
 1       16         Colorado   2018-02-10 00:00:00    2       2
 1       18         Colorado   2018-02-17 00:00:00    3       2
 1       19         Colorado   2018-02-24 00:00:00    4       2
 1       92          Civil     2018-03-03 00:00:00    1       3
 1       91          Civil     2018-03-10 00:00:00    2       3
 1       88          Civil     2018-03-17 00:00:00    3       3
 1       92          Civil     2018-03-24 00:00:00    4       3
 1       90          Civil     2018-03-31 00:00:00    5       3
 1       19         Colorado   2018-03-03 00:00:00    1       3
 1       26         Colorado   2018-03-10 00:00:00    2       3
 1       25         Colorado   2018-03-17 00:00:00    3       3
 1       27         Colorado   2018-03-24 00:00:00    4       3
 1       24         Colorado   2018-03-31 00:00:00    5       3
```

Comment: You might look at adding a field that is similar to "group by" Month with the "sum" for the month.  And doing some trick to signal or set the value for the "max" date for that month and year.  In general I would consider reworking the query to give you what will make your report easier to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in your query rather than trying to get it to work directly in SSRS. There might be a simpler way than this but this is just based on your existing query.

**Please note this is untested and just off the top of my head** so it may need some editing before it will work.

```
SELECT * INTO #t FROM YOUR_EXISTING_QUERY

SELECT DISTINCT
        PRCo
        , udDivision
        , YEAR(PREndDate) AS Yr
        , MONTH(PREndDate) AS Mnth
        , FIRST_VALUE(EMPCOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY PRCo, udDivision, YEAR(PREndDate), MONTH(PREndDate) ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS OpeningEMPCOUNT
        , LAST_VALUE(EMPCOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY PRCo, udDivision, YEAR(PREndDate), MONTH(PREndDate) ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS CLosing_EMPCOUNT
FROM #t
```

Yo might need to include `Type` not sure what this does but you get the idea hopefully.

The FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE functions simply get the first/last value within the partition defined, in your case PRCo, udDivision and then just the year and month portion of the payroll end date, the first and last positions are determined by the order clause, in this case row number.

Comment: Agree with this approach. I personally always code the sql for SSRS reports as stored procedures which makes development and maintenance far simpler, not to mention more efficient. I'd also avoid using a temp table and would use a CTE for this.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. After tweaking your answer I was able to get what I needed. I Appreciate the help!